# Configurações da linguagem Go

Tags: golang

Preciso fazer um trabalho da faculdade e escolhi fazer na linguagem Go pois queria aprender uma linguagem nova. Ontem instalei o .msi do site e vi que precisava configurar as variáveis `GOPATH`, `PATH` e `GOROOT`. Eu configurei elas da seguinte maneira:

- GOPATH = `C:\Users\Gustavo\goprojects` (onde a pasta `goprojects` eu criei e é onde eu quero que fique todos os meus projetos da linguagem Go)
- GOROOT = `C:\Go\` (pasta onde foi instalado a linguagem Go)
- PATH = `C:\Users\Gustavo\goprojects\bin`

Até ai tudo bem. Porém eu uso a IDE Eclipse e pesquisando eu vi que tem um plugin chamado GoClipse que faz o Eclipse ser uma IDE da linguagem Go, então eu a instalei pelo marketplace do próprio Eclipse.

Depois de tudo isto feito, criei um novo projeto Go e coloquei para o projeto ser no caminho `C:\Users\Gustavo\goprojects`, e criei um novo .go dentro de uma pasta que esta fica dentro da pasta src. Quando fui escrever um Hello World, toda vez que eu tentava fazer ele completar sozinho o código ele aparece um erro ai eu fui ver e vi que precisava baixar um outro plugin para funcionar *o auto-completing*, e este plugin chama `gocode` que é um projeto que está no GitHub.

E aqui está meu problema. Onde e como eu devo baixar esta pasta e como ativá-la no meu Eclipse? Eu configurei as variáveis corretamente? Preciso fazer algo a mais?

P.S.: Uso Windows 8.1, tenho o git instalado.

Comment: normalmente você não substitui o PATH completamente, mas adiciona novos diretórios/pastas; no seu caso seria assim: PATH = %PATH%;C:\Users\Gustavo\goprojects\bin

Answer (score 1):

Supondo que o projeto `gocode` ao qual se refere é este: https://github.com/nsf/gocode,
basta rodar o comando:

```
go get -u github.com/nsf/gocode
```

Isso fará com que o pacote seja devidamente instalado e seu binário fique disponível na pasta `$GOPATH\bin`.

Answer (score 0):

Gustavo,
estou programando em GO, aconselho muito focar nessa linguagem.. e uma sugestão pois sou programador a muitos anos..
Usa o linux para programar em GO, pode ser até uma VirtualBox e eu gosto de usar o ATOM, tem vários plugins interessantes.

Answer (score 0):

Independente de qualquer projeto que usar, eu recomendo usar a recomendação de workspaces do Go.
Na [documentação](https://golang.org/doc/code.html#Workspaces) eles explicam como você deve criar esses workspaces.

Com isso você consegue deixar seus projetos muito bem estruturados, e padronizados.